# C++ friend vs public

Tags: c++, public, friend

What's is the difference between friend and public functions declared in a class? What's the point of using a friend function when we can make it public and have the same access?

Comment: friend function != member (non-static) function

Comment: a simple google search will answer your question. read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_friend_functions.htm

Comment: Use a friend function to allow access to private internal members from that external, non-member function.

Answer (score 6):

`public` refers to the access level of class **member** functions.  A **member** function can be `public, protected or private`.

`friend` refers to **non-member** functions.  Declaring a function `friend` allows the **non-member** function access to class' `private` data.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that a `public` member function is a member function with an implicit `this` argument, whereas a `friend` function is a non-member function that can use `private` and `protected` members of the class.

You would typically write a `friend` function in order to work with a class object as the *second* argument: a constructor `foo::foo( const bar& x )` that needs to see the internals of the new `foo` and its source `x` would be a `public` member of `foo` and a `friend` of bar.  Another common idiom is that, if you want to be able to add a `foo` to (for example) an `int`, programmers expect addition to be commutative and expressions such as `1 + foo() + 1` to work.  The version with the `foo` as the second argument would be declared `friend foo operator+( int, const foo& );` so that it could use the internals of its second argument.

Answer (score 0):

A friend class in C++ can access the "private" and "protected" members of the class in which it is declared as a friend.

public - Any class can refer to the field or call the method.

**If this helped please voted up & marked “accepted”**